# How to turn a list of values from a rich textbox to formatted list C#

Tags: c#

I have a rich textbox where the user will enter values like this with a line return after each line.

```
   A12345
   B12345
```

I want to reformat these values into a like this, to put in a SQL `IN` clause

```
   ('A12345', 'B12345')
```

Note: the last value can't have a `[,]` following.

Thanks!

Comment: string.join works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
string result = "(" + string.Join(",", textBox.Text.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => "'" + s + "'")) + ")";
```

Comment: Really close i need a ' after each value seperated by a comma. I'm getting ('A12345
  B1235')

Comment: The above will add the ' correctly after. Have you copied it correctly ?

Comment: Hmm that's what i had but using Prasaz  split it worke

               string = "(" + string.Join(",", Textbox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => "'" + s + "'")) + ")";

Comment: Right, adding "\n" looks much better. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the text using new line and return carriage.

```
string[] splitString = textstring.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`
```

`

Comment: This doesn't answer the full question.